# Multivariable Calc At what point does r(t) intersect the yz plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The Position vector of a particle at time t is given by r(t) = <1/3(t^3 - 3t), t^2, 5> . At what point or points does the particle cross the yz-plane?

Comment: i let r(t) = 1 to start out and got a final answer of < 0, 25 , 5> is this correct? I do believe there are many correct answers to this depending on what you let r(t) equal in the beginning. Can anyone help or confirm?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The point $(x,y,z)$ is on the $yz$-plane iff $x=0$.

Comment: thanks yeah i got that i actually have an answer but im just not quite sure if its right . Thanks though for confirming that i at least got that part correct. More insight would be appreciated : )